# File uploaded successfully, but upload progress bar on Android always 0%

Tags: android, file-upload, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I create a ProgressDialog like with variable name "dialog".

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
```

This is my ProgressDialog code:

```
//on upload button Click
            if(selectedFilePath != null){
//                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","Uploading File...",true);
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                dialog.setMessage("Uploading File");
                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                dialog.setMax(100);
                dialog.show();

                final int totalProgressTime = 100;

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        int jumpTime = 0;

                        while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                                jumpTime += 10;
                                dialog.setProgress(jumpTime);
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                        uploadFile(selectedFilePath);

                    }
                }).start();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose a File First",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

My file successful to upload. but something wrong on my Progress Bar, It's always 0% and not raise up.

It's look like this:

[image: Upload Progress]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not manipulate Views from non-ui thread. Use a `Handler` to update the progress.

Edit:

See [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/updating-progressbar-status-from-a-non-ui-thread-working-thread-using-handler-in-android/) for a complete example.

Comment: Did you have an example for Handler?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest extending [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). There are tutorial online, such as http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/ which will help you with uploading files

Comment: I had saw that tutorial, But I don't understand how to add apache http library